# c# get new location of exe after moving

Tags: c#, path, exe, move

If I run my exe, you can get the current full path with

`Path.GetFullPath(Application.ExecuteablePath)`

Now I'm moving the exe out of my executable directory.

For example to `C:\Users\Felix\Desktop\myExe.exe`

How can I get the new location path of my exe, while my exe is running and wont be restart ?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Windows should not let you move an executable while it is still open.

Comment: You cannot. There is no hook for this. You *could* implement a system wide hook on files being created, but I suspect you may try to solve something that's not really a problem. Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Phylogenesis My OS is Win 10 and there it works? I can move the exe wherever I want. But than I dont cant find the new Location

Comment: While windows will let you move, I have a hunch that the program is still executing from the original directory. Could you tell us why you are trying to do this? Maybe there is a different way to accomplish this.

Comment: Sorry for being naive here, the code that moved the exe surely knows the destination location? `File.Move(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)`

Comment: @nvoigt and @ Wyatt Shuler: Because if the user is moving my application you cannot open it the next time. So I want the hold them in these one directory. Maybe therfore you have a other solution? Sry, I'm new in C#:)

Comment: Are you assuming that, since you moved the file corresponding to the currently executing code, some how automatically, windows has re-spawned the process from this new exe path and a call like `Application.ExecuteablePath` should get aware of this? If that's the case, then you are misunderstanding the process of `Loading`. Moving the file in question, does not respawn your process, and hence none of the BCL code which usually points to the executable will point to this new location

Comment: Windows just let's you move an executable file which is currently executing and maintains a cached file which represents the original file from where your process was spawned. This is just an educated guess on my part

Comment: @Vikhram: yes thats correct if I know where the new location is. But first I have to find out, where the user is put my exe file

Comment: If the move action is external to the application, then it is impossible to know the path categorically. You can write heuristics to do that using File system hooks though - sounds like an XY problem to me

Comment: I think you are solving the wrong problem. It's like putting GPS in all my socks because I sometimes move them. If a user moves your executable, that's **his** problem, not yours.

Comment: okay thanks guys for help :)

Comment: You can use FileSystemWatcher to see yourself getting moved.  Not so sure this is a useful feature.